# PHP Search for arrays and extract comma

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have one array

```
Array (
    [1]=>123,456,789,3255
    [2]=>585,478,437,1237
)
```

Search Text = 12

output I want -> 123,1237

What way should I go?

```
$array = array();
array_push($array,'1234',534,75,746);
array_push($array,'164',574,752,755);
array_push($array,'154',58,754,76);

$search_text = '75';

I want Output = 

75,752,755,754
```

Comment: Any code attempt?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't written any code yet, but the series and what I want is obvious

Comment: But not obvious to you?

Comment: I added my codes

Comment: `I want Output` is still not a code attempt.

Comment: I do not know what will come there.

Comment: You could try a "loop" for starters. That would be at least an attempt.

Comment: Your sample code will not generate an array that looks like your sample data. Please clarify which is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `strpos` and a loop.

```php
$numbers = array();
array_push($numbers,'1234', 534, 75, 746);
array_push($numbers,'164', 574, 752, 755);
array_push($numbers,'154', 58, 754, 76);

$searchNumber = '75';

$output = [];

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if (strpos((string) $number, $searchNumber) !== false) {
        $output[] = $number;
    }
}

// 75, 752, 755, 754
echo implode(", ", $output);
```

If you are using PHP 8 you could even replace the `strpos` with `str_contains` function

```
if (str_contains($number, $searchNumber)) { 
    $output[] = $number;
}
```

[RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/str_contains)

[str_contains](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/str_contains)

Comment: Since there was a mixture of types in the original array. I was just going to cast them to a string since you are just looking for the characters instead of the numbers then.

I've edited the original answer to cast all the numbers to strings before using strpos on them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = [];
$array = [];
$toSearch = '75';
array_push($array,'1234',534,75,746);
array_push($array,'164',574,752,755);
array_push($array,'154',58,754,76);
// If your array is one dimension
$result = array_filter($array, function($el) use ($toSearch) {
  return strpos((string) $el, (string) $toSearch);
});
// For 2D array:
foreach ($array as $cur) {
  $result = array_merge($result, array_filter($cur, function($el) use ($toSearch) {
    return strpos((string) $el, (string) $toSearch);
  }));
}
```